# Javascript UTC Date issue in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, utc

I'm currently making a jQuery Mobile application and using Phone Gap to deploy to multiple platforms. Unfortunately, I'm noticing that there seems to be some inconsistent behavior between the desktop and mobile compatibilities in using Javascript's family of UTC date functions.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with Android, iPhone, and / or Blackberry in this regard?  I currently think that it's a native browser issue as Chrome and Firefox seem to have the expected behavior.

The normal usage of:

```
var d = new Date();
var utc_month = d.getUTCMonth();
```

Yields an `int` value for desktop browsers and a `NaN` value for utc_month on mobile browsers.  Any thoughts?  I wasn't able to find much on PhoneGap about exposing datetime from native browsers~

Comment: Just tested on iOS 4.3 and works as expected, returning `6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example works fine for me on Android 2.2 with PhoneGap (after changing 'int utc_month ...' to 'var utc_month ...').

Do you have the same typo in your code? I ran the following:

```
var utc_month = d.getUTCMonth();  alert (utc_month);
```

6 gets alerted.

Comment: My mistake, I did have the `var` keyword in my code originally.  I will edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: What device(s) and OS are you seeing the NaN?

Comment: Android 2.2 and Blackberry Browser 6.  Though there have been some developments in my searches.  I'll update my post shortly.

Comment: After further review, I do think that this may have been an issue with my code having some sort of typo earlier on.  My mistake.